# What can I use instead of TFMail for a form-mail script?

Tags: php, perl, email, forms, cgi

TFMail was a popular PERL CGI Form Mail script at one time.  So far it has served our purposes.  It is very easy to set up and configure.

Unfortunately, it only has basic functionality.  It works well when you want users to fill in a form and have the result emailed to a specified email address.

Can someone recommend a script ( maybe a PHP script ) that I can use to replace TFMail?

Here's the functionality that I like in TFMail:

Set up an HTML form and point the action at the script

- The result of the form gets sent via email
- Specify the recipient of the email
- Create a template for the email sent to the recipient
- Create a emplate for the email sent to the
  submitter
- Create a template for the
  log file
- Allow file attachments
- Redirect to a thank-you/confirmation page

Comment: Haven't checked for feature completeness, therefore only a comment: unlike most mail scripts floating around the net, [NMS FormMail](http://nms-cgi.sf.net/) is security audited. This is a very important aspect which is often ignored.

Comment: This question says what is good about TF mail.  What does the qner need that TF mail doesn't do?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons. If you use a framework, it will have something, most likely.  If not, there is HTML::MIME, Zend_Mail (can be used with or w/o Zend), and many more just a google search away. In the late 90's, it seemed that everyone starting out in something like Perl or PHP would write a mailer as a right-of-passage or something so there are a million of them out there.

```
http://htmlmimemail.tuxfamily.org/
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/sending-email-zend-mail/
```

etc...

(Creating our own frameworks is the new right-of-passage, I think.)